# How to save incoming push-notifications to a history in angular

Tags: angular, angular9, web-push

I have a swpush service and want to save all incoming PushNotifications to an array.
Is that possible through a swpush methode?

I couldn't figure out a way to archive this behavior and think it might not be possible. In that case, is there a best practise to create a PushNot history? The only way I can think of is to fetch the notifications seperatly from the backend, but if possible I'd just like to save the PushNot payload, when receiving it.

Comment: Please show the code. It isn't clear at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you can. You receive the payload in the `push` event of the service worker. There you need to save the payload somewhere, for example in `IndexedDB`.

Comment: @MichaelD I added the code of my notification service. I aim to add some kind of function which get's triggered, in case there's a incoming PushNotification, that pushes the payload to an array.
But I can't figure out how to trigger a function when there's a incoming pushnotification

Comment: @collimarco thanks for the Idea!
it seems like i'm searching the wrong keywords though and still can't figure out how/where the push event is defined...
Is there some Blog/Wiki entry where somthing similar is done?

Comment: @cezonp The `push` even should be defined in your *service worker*.

Comment: @collimarco I'm sorry, somehow I still don't get it...
should I create a "push" methode within the serviceworker, which gets called  automatically when a Pushnoification is received, or what do you mean by defining " the push"?